# How do I data bind Control.Enabled to !(field)?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a (varchar) field Foo which can only be specified if (bit) Bar is *not* true.  I would like the textbox in which Foo is displayed to be *disabled* when Bar is true -- essentially, `FooBox.Enabled = !isBar`.  I'm trying to do something like

```
FooBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", source, "!isBar"));
```

but of course the bang in there throws an exception.  I've also tried constructs like "isBar != true" or "isBar <> true", but none work.  Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: +1 because I googled "c# control enabled data binding" and this was the first thing that came up, and is literally the exact situation I'm facing.

Comment: See [binding a usercontrol to the opposite of a bool property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19718906/298054).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried doing something like this a while ago and the best I could come up with was either

a) Changing the source class to also have a NotBar property and bind to that

b) Make a dumb wrapper class around source that has a NotBar property and bind to that.

Comment: I had an idea sort of like this, but I figured it *should* be possible without resorting to this sort of hack.  Apparently not?

Comment: I agree that it's a hack. I was quite disappointed by it as well.  For my project I basically resorted to making my own system that would handle the the source changing and change the control accordingly.  I haven't looked at it much, but WPF databinding is much more advanced, if that's an option.

Comment: I'm going to look into WPF when I get a chance.  Sadly, the project I'm asking about is just about in the can, so a switch is not an option at this point.  But I may transition before my next one...

Comment: FYI, I wound up using this as an answer to one of my other questions (about radio buttons).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, Databind uses reflection to find the member passed as the 3rd string argument. You cannot pass an expression there, just the member name.

Comment: I think Jake has the general idea (making a Property that calculates what you want) but it still feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score -1):

if isBar is a property of the source class (otherwise you need a property of a class to do the binding) this should work:

```
FooBox.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", source, "isBar");
```

but remember that source.isBar must exist and be a boolean.

Comment: I understand the basic concept, it's just that it seems kind of limited.  I was hoping you'd have a little more flexibility.