# Enabling List item of DropdownList in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the code as,

```
<asp:ListItem Value="Above 50" Text="Above 50"  Enabled='<%# (((string)(Eval("Gender"))).Contains("Male"))? true:false%>'></asp:ListItem>
```

the condition is,if the user is male,then the item 'Above 50' should enable in the dropdownList,else not. here, 'Gender' is nothing but a bound field.

the error showing is,

```
Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem does not have a DataBinding event.
```

what is wrong in the code?

Comment: Where does the DropDownList control located? Could you post the code of it's parent control?

Comment: `Contains` returns a Bool, so `'<%# ((string)(Eval("Gender"))).Contains("Male")%>'` should be sufficient. Or `'<%# Eval("Gender").ToString().Contains("Male")%>'`

Answer (score 1):

The [ListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have any **data binding** events. Hence `Eval()` cannot be used here.

You need to call the **DataBound** Event on your Drop Down list and perform the check there.

something like this -

```
protected void MyDropDownList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ddl = sender as DropDownList;
            foreach (ListItem item in ddl.Items)
            {
                if (Gender == "Male")
                {
                    item.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        }
```

Please note that `enabled = false` will remove the list item while `disabled = disabled` will only grey it out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are approaching the problem in slightly the wrong way. This question, and the answers, seem to be exactly what you are looking for: [How do I data bind Control.Enabled to !(field)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345225/how-do-i-data-bind-control-enabled-to-field)

In your case, you would bind to a function or value that checks the Gender value.